# What's the difference in Python between creating an attribute and declaring it in the class?

Tags: python, descriptor

These two codes will give two different outputs, why ?

```
class Test:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return 42
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        pass

class A:
    a = Test()

a = A()
print(a.a) // print 42
a.a = 0
print(a.a) // print 42
```

And

```
class Test:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return 42
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        pass

class A:
    pass

a = A()
a.a = Test()
print(a.a) // print <__main__.Test object at 0xb700d6cc>
a.a = 0
print(a.a) // print 0
```

How are stored attributes in the Python engine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Test` class isn't called "attribute", it's a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors). Descriptors work, by definition, only when stored on a (new style, for the poor Python 2 users) class. Descriptor objects on non-class objects have no special meaning, they are treated like any other object. Their `__get__` method is ignored when they are retrieved, and their `__set__` is ignored when they are replaced.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, class `Test` acts a descriptor for your class A, as it defines `__get__` and `__set__` methods.

If you use `any class` having `__get__`, `__set__` methods, as an attribute in your class, it acts as a `descriptor` for your class, and not as an `attribute`.
So, when you assign something to that variable, the `descriptor's` `__set__` method is called, and when you try to access it, the `descriptor's` `__get__` method is invoked. Descriptors just provides access to class's attributes through `getters` and `setters`

So, when you do `a = Test()` in your class A, the descriptors `__get__` method is invoked and value `42` is returned and assigned to it.

Whereas in the second case, you are instantiating `class Test` just like every other class.
So, `a.a` represents the reference to the instance of class `Test`.

Comment: I don't agree with your formulation _"So, when you do a = Test() in your class A, ....etc"_ -- IMO it should be : Placing ``a = Test()`` in the definition of your class ``A`` makes ``a`` a descriptor when the definition of class ``A`` is executed. So when an access is then done to descriptor ``a`` in instance ``a`` through a dot notation, its ``__get__`` method is invoked and value ``42`` is returned. The object ``42`` isn't assigned to anything but your sentence gives the impression that ``42`` is assigned to the identifier ``a`` in ``A`` at the creation of the class ``A``